Expression evaluation failed. The message body is not a valid JSON. Error reading JObject from JsonReader
I am new to Azure and API Management.  I have an OAuth resource from which I must get a token for every request.
I am repeatedly getting 500 Internal Server Error, but I have finally root caused down to a single issue - retrieving the token from my send-request variable and placing it into my backend request header.
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="tokenstate" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://xxx/token</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>{{Named Value}}</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>@{
           return "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&scope={{Named Value}}&assertion={{Named Value}}";
           }
        </set-body>
    </send-request>

    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (String)((IResponse)context.Variables["tokenstate"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header exists-action="delete" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"/>
    <set-backend-service backend-id="{{Backend Service}}" />


Can you please provide trace details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector

Obviously, the response from 'https://xxx/token' is not a valid JSON. Try to make a request through Postman and see what the response is being returned by your endpoint.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
